# Convert time duration string to seconds in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a series of data that is outputted from an application in the following format.

```
8d 21h 33m  
30s  
6m 32s  
1m 40s  
54m 6s  
11m 32s  
5d 3h 34m  
30s  
7m 40s  
19h 57m 49s  
1h 36m 9s  
1m 3s  
5m 11s  
19m 39s
```

I'd like to show this as the number of seconds in the next column in excel. If I was doing this in php or python I could split the string on each letter (h & m) but I've no idea how to do this in excel. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should work:

```
Public Function to_seconds(data As String)
    Dim LArray() As String
    LArray = Split(data)
    total_time = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(LArray)
        m = LArray(i)
        If m <> "" Then
            q = Right(m, 1)
            tt = Left(m, Len(m) - 1)
            ta = 0
            Select Case q
                Case "d"
                    ta = 86400
                Case "h"
                    ta = 3600
                Case "m"
                    ta = 60
                Case "s"
                    ta = 1
            End Select
            If IsNumeric(tt) Then
                total_time = total_time + (Int(tt) * ta)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    to_seconds = total_time
End Function
```

Open VBA /Macros with ALT+ F11 and under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module. Paste the code on the right side.

If your data is in cell `A1` then cell `B1`must be `=to_seconds(A1)`.

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I was happy to try and get there with a little help but now I've seen the solution it might have taken a bit longer then I thought.

Comment: As you know php and python surely you can understand what I've done and improve this function.

Comment: I don't think I can claim to know php and python. More I can do certain things such as in this case splitting strings. I certainly don't know enough to optimise a given piece of code

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the non-VBA version of jcbermu's answer. Open up the Name Manager and create a name with this formula, where A1 is the first row of your data.

```
=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$A1,"d","*86400+"),"h","*3600+"),"m","*60+"),"s","*1+")&"0")
```

Give it a name, for example `eval` and type `=eval` in to a cell and autofill down.

Evaluate is a hidden function in Excel that only works when it's defined in the name manager. Simply typing the formula into a cell normally does not work.